# How slf4j+log4j application resumes work When the hard disk is full

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I used the logging system in a web application.The log system is `slf4j + log4j`.

The configuration file is as follows.

Now I have a problem.

In the first step, I used a pressure test program. Unfortunately, the hard disk was filled and the log could not be output.

In the second step, I deleted the extra logs and the hard disk regained space. Unfortunately, my log system could not continue working.

I had to restart my service to recover the log system.

This is obviously not the best solution. How can I get the logs to work again?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds" debug="false">
    <property name="LOG_ROOT" value="logs/"/>
    <property name="SVC_NAME" value="robot-test"/>

    <appender name="AllLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}${HOSTNAME}.${SVC_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <!--<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">-->
            <!--<fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}${HOSTNAME}.${SVC_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>-->
            <!--<MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>-->
            <!--<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">-->
                <!--<maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>-->
            <!--</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>-->
        <!--</rollingPolicy>-->


        <encoder charset="UTF8">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${logging.stdout.appender.level}</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder charset="UTF8">
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.smzy.commonservice" level="WARN" addtivity="false"/>

    <root level="${logging.root.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="AllLog"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should probably not fill your harddrive and expect things to continue normally.

Comment: I have cleaned up the disk, but the log service seems to have stopped completely. I think the log service should resume working after I clean the disk

Comment: If the environment is borked and you have no resources, you can't expect a random service to handle that gracefully. You're at fault for not providing enough space.

Comment: Yes, the first error is because I don't have enough resources. I don't know if log4j has the service to listen to the disk. If there is, then when I provide resources again, log4j should resume working.

Comment: I have not blamed this library, I just want to ask if there is this feature. If there is, but I didn't find it in the document, I can configure it. If not, it will face reality.

Comment: Running out of space is considered a serious error, you can't expect to keep going normally after that. At minimum you'll be restarting your services. Then you'll be yelling at the person responsible for providing too little storage space.